# I damaged a caliper slide pin bolt, should I replace the whole pin?

Tags: braking, fastener, caliper

When replacing the brake pads and discs on a 2006 1.3 Suzuki ignis I damaged a bolt which fastens the caliper onto its mounting bracket. The bolt was stuck on and I thought it probably needed replacing. I tried to find a replacement bolt, but ruined the original threading an incorrect nut on.

Now feeling silly, I ordered a set of slide pins with bolts and rubber boots to ensure I had the correct part.

The only reason I'm considering this is that perhaps the threads of the pin got damaged as well as the bolt, and so the pin may need changing too. Should I replace the original (perfectly working) pin with a new one? Or should I assume that if the new bolt threads into the pin okay then there is no problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Maybe I'm just unfamiliar with your brake system, but could you clarify how the caliper, bolts, and pins are assembled together? If you use a bolt to fasten the caliper onto its bracket, where does the pin fit into this? Maybe considering adding a picture? Also this statement is confusing: "tried to find a replacement bolt, but ruined the original [by] threading an incorrect nut on". If you ruined the bolt with the wrong nut, then how did the threading on the pin get damaged?

Comment: And if all else fails, post a pic of the damage and the associated parts ... Like they say, "*A picture is worth a 1000 words ...*" :o)